# How does order of the base vectors affect a Transformation Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given two basis $A$ and $B$, the linear transformation $T$ transforms a vector in base $A$ to a vector in base $B$. This transformation can obviously be represented by a matrix $M$.

But how are changes in the order of the base vectors (column vectors of $A$ and $B$) reflected in the Matrix $M$.

Here is what i have so far:

$MA=B$

$M=BA^{-1}$

$M=B\frac{1}{det(B)}adj(B)$

$M=B\frac{1}{det(B)}cof(B)^T$, where $cof(B)$ is the cofactor Matrix of $B$.

However, it is not obvious to me how changes order of the column Vectors of $A$ or $B$ are reflected in the Cofactor Matrix or in the matrix $M$.

Comment: Think about what effect changing the order of basis vectors has on coordinates of a vector, then relate that to the columns and rows of $M$.